# How to add link only one specific page?

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a link just one page out of all the pages. I've tried some different ways, but that is not working and closing the image slide simultaneously.

```js
var photo = ["image/pic0.jpg", "image/pic1.jpg", "image/pic2.jpg", "image/pic3.jpg", "image/pic4.jpg"];
var imgTag = document.querySelector(".slide-pic");
var count = 0;
var time = 0;

window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(next, 5000);
};

function next() {
  count++;
  if (count >= photo.length) {
    count = 0;
    imgTag.src = photo[count];
  } else {
    imgTag.src = photo[count];
  }
}

function prev() {
  count--;
  if (count < 0) {
    count = photo.length - 1;
    imgTag.src = photo[count];
  } else {
    imgTag.src = photo[count];
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="front-pic">
  <button class="left-btn" onclick="prev()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
  <img id="pic-link" class="slide-pic" src="image/pic0.jpg">
  <button class="right-btn" onclick="next()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: i wanted to go another page from a particular image. it also has a time sliding

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you were trying to achieve but I still gave it a try. Try the code snippet below and see if it works for you.

```js
var photo = [
            "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/pacific-coast-highway-101-oregon-600w-1340723072.jpg",
            "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/cargo-train-departing-station-during-600w-1153325710.jpg",
            "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/california-united-states-pacific-coast-600w-322331276.jpg",
            "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/piha-beach-on-west-coast-600w-154908542.jpg",
            "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/sea-cliff-bridge-along-grand-600w-167705717.jpg"
        ];
        var imgTag = document.querySelector(".slide-pic");
        var count = 0;
        var time = 0;

        window.onload = function () {
            setTimeout(next, 5000);
        };

        function next() {
            count++;
            if (count >= photo.length) {
                count = 0;
                imgTag.src = photo[count];
            }
            else {
                imgTag.src = photo[count];
            }
        }

        function prev() {
            count--;
            if (count < 0) {
                count = photo.length - 1;
                imgTag.src = photo[count];
            }
            else {
                imgTag.src = photo[count];
            }
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="front-pic">
        <button class="left-btn" onclick="prev()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
        <img id="pic-link" class="slide-pic" width="200" height="200" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/summer-landscape-blue-sky-on-600w-313318763.jpg">
        <button class="right-btn" onclick="next()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </div>
```

Please note the changes that I made in the original code.

- I'm using `/` in the path of the images rather than `\`.
- Changed the images. These are available online and were added only for the purpose of demonstration. You, of course, can give the path to your images. But, when you give a path to a static file, give a relative path instead of absolute.
- I added font-awesome CDN, as I noticed you were using it for the icons in the buttons. You can change this one with the one you're currently using.

Comment: i wanted to go another page from a particular image like google.com or yahoo.com or any other page by click on the image. it also has a time sliding

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you want to add a link on the first image that you have, and not on the other images? or do you want to add one link to every image source?

Comment: "Do you want to add a link on the first image that you have, and not on the other images?" This is i want